Как убрать лишние символы в xml-файле?
Исключение:

Знак ".", шестнадцатеричное значение 0x00, не может стоять в начале имени, строка 1, позиция 2.

Код:
string content = File.ReadAllText(_xml_file);
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(content);
...

Штуки типа SanitizeXmlString из https://seattlesoftware.wordpress.com/2008/09/11/hexadecimal-value-0-is-an-invalid-character/ не помогают — портится xml-строка.
Файл по типу такого:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<protocol name="protocol" date_time="2024-08-16T13:14:00" description="Test">
    <check name="check1" description="RegularCTCheck" check_datetime="2024-08-16T13:14:00">
        <header stationname="" type="" number="" />
        <param standard="GOST" I1ном="" I2ном="" S2ном="" Rном="" Tизм="" Tном="" Ukn="" Ikn="" />
        <result MagPercent="6.0%" Rизм="9.900 Ом" Rприв="9.900 Ом" Rпогр="0.0%" Ukn="156.452 В" Ikn="0.123237 А" Ukn2="0.000 В" Ikn2="0.000000 А" Ktr="1002.4" KtrPogr="0.0%" Ph="-176.6°" Pol="Negative" />
        <VAC entriescount="13">
            <VACentry number="1" Uизм="82.68 В" Iизм="1.5866 А" P="141.25824 Вт" U50Hz="82.6777 В" I50Hz="1.5866 А" />
            <VACentry number="2" Uизм="82.19 В" Iизм="1.5148 А" P="128.75563 Вт" U50Hz="82.1941 В" I50Hz="1.5148 А" />
            ...
        </VAC>
    </check>
</protocol>


И еще :


Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
Пожалуйста, отредактируйте свой исходный вопрос и предоставьте следующее:
(1) Правильно сформированный (well-formed) пример XML-файла.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т. е. логику, и ваш код, который попытается ее реализовать.
(3) Желаемый вывод на основе данных примера в пункте 1 выше.
Все в вопросе в виде текста, без картинок.

Загрузка идет через XDocument. Остальные подробности не разглашаю ибо не имеют отношение к делу.

Вполне возможно, что ваш XML-файл имеет в самом начале так называемую метку Byte Order Mark (BOM).

Используйте метод Load, загрузите ваш документ при помощи XmlReader, TextReader, обычно это решает проблемы с кодировками. Чтобы вам не пришлось думать что за кодировка у файла. https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load?view=net-8.0#system-xml-linq-xdocument-load(system-io-textreader)  https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load?view=net-8.0#system-xml-linq-xdocument-load(system-xml-xmlreader)

Судя по скриншоту, на символ приходится по два байта. Файл сохранён в кодировке UTF-16, но без BOM. Просто пересохраните его либо с BOM, либо в UTF-8. Банально в Блокноте откройте и пересохраните в нужной кодировке.

Тут возникает вопрос: откуда вы взяли файл в такой кодировке? Сами сотворили - больше не делайте так. Откуда-то получили - избегайте того места.

BOM хоть и опциональна для UTF-16, но, как видим, многие API отказываются с ней работать, потому как не знают порядок байтов (и не пытаются гадать).

Извините, у меня нет варианта брать или не брать такие файлы. Партия сказала надо - значит надо.

var encoding = new UnicodeEncoding(bigEndian: false, byteOrderMark: false); string content = File.ReadAllText(_xml_file, encoding); - читайте так.

".", шестнадцатеричное значение 0x00, является недопустимым знаком., строка 5, позиция 30.

Причем не читаются те файлы, где в notepad++ NUL

И когда читаешь содержимое этих файлов где NUL текст вообще завершается.

Вроде удалось решить проблему добавлением Sanitize

var _encoding = new UnicodeEncoding(bigEndian: false, byteOrderMark: false);
string content = SanitizeXmlString(File.ReadAllText(_xml_file, _encoding));

Предположение, что это так называемый Byte Order Mark (BOM) создаёт проблему.
void Main()
{
    string _xml_file = @"...";
    string content = File.ReadAllText(_xml_file);

    string _byteOrderMarkUtf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
    
    if (content.StartsWith(_byteOrderMarkUtf8, StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        content = content.Remove(0, _byteOrderMarkUtf8.Length);
    }
    
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(content);
}

Вот как выглядит BOM в начале XML-файла:


Спасибо. Попробую. Да. Ещё что интересно, если открыть такой файл в двоичном представлении, в некоторых из них вообще нет нулей, хотя ошибку выдает

Для этого вы можете попробовать Total Commander Viewer (F3): https://www.ghisler.com/.

@YitzhakKhabinsky если на то пошло, Notepad++ покажет кодировку сразу в статус-баре без изучений битобайтов. И даже позволит перекодировать в любую другую.

@aepot, К сожалению, Notepad++ отображает только UTF-8-BOM в статус-баре, но не отображает сам символ в XML-документе.

@YitzhakKhabinsky а зачем вам сам символ? Кодировка определена корректно, перекодируйте во что угодно.

Нет. Не помогло BOM. Попробовал открыть листером тотал командера. Адекватно отображается только в UTF-16.

Итак, нам нужно провести дальнейшее расследование. При просмотре XML-файла в TC Lister выберите в меню Options, 3 Hex, сделайте снимок экрана (screen shot) и добавьте его к исходному вопросу.

Кстати попробовал, System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode на некоторых файлах работает - на некоторых нет. Видно где-то BE где-то LE.
